# How to properly subtract 2 numbers taken from String after converting them to int array

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm currently stuck in algorithm which takes two Strings (which are made from numbers) as an argument. Steps are:

1. Convert String to int array
2. Reverse this array so from String(123456) array would look like: int[654321].
3. Subtract values from two made arrays and save it to third(result) array using given algorithm.
4. Reading values from third(result) table, read them backwards and save result to String.

Basically, I'm currently on algorithms and data structure course on Uni and we wrote this algorithm in our class, but it's only working when I'm subtracting A-B, where A > B. What is my current problem is that I need to refactor this to the point where I can subtract B from A, even though B > A.

I've tried to add some 'if' statements which would depend on A > B || A < B but I don't think that it would lead my anywhere.

Conversion function which cannot be changed anyway:

```java
public static int[] convert(String number, int size)
{
    int[] tab = new int[size];
    int position = number.length() - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (position < 0) tab[i] = 0;
        else tab[i] = number.charAt(position--) - 48;
    }
    return tab;
}

public static String substract(String number1, String number2)
{
    String result = "";
    int size = Math.max(number1.length(), number2.length()) + 1;
    int[] tA = new int[size];
    int[] tB = new int[size];
    int[] tW = new int[size];

    tA = convert(number1, size);
    tB = convert(number2, size);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) tW[i] = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
    {
        tW[i+1] += (tW[i] + tA[i] - tB[i] + 10) / 10 - 1;
        tW[i] = (tW[i] + tA[i] - tB[i] + 10) % 10;
    }

    while(size > 1 && tW[size-1] == 0) size--;

    for(int i = size; i > 0; i--) result += (char)(tW[i-1] + 48);

    return result;
}
```

I expect that output of subtract("12", "20") would be -8 but actual output is /92.

Comment: The point here is also that I would have to use this and it should work even when my String length would be 21474836.

Comment: Try setting A as the array with larger length. And if they are equal, compare the left most digit.

Comment: Are you using Java 8+ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some example solutions using Java 8. If you are allowed to use them, I'd recommend using streams as they really fit your problem:

- convert: return the numeric value of each char in string, into an int array.

```
    int[] convert(String s) {
        return s.chars().map(Character::getNumericValue).toArray();
    }
```

- reverse: reverse an int array.

```
    int[] reverse(int[] toReverse) {
        return IntStream.range(0, toReverse.length)
                .map(i -> toReverse[toReverse.length - 1 - i])
                .toArray();
    }
```

- substract: for a range between 0 and the biggest length, return the value of the int in `a` minus the int in `b` at position `i`, if both exist, in form of an array of results.

```
    int[] substract(int[] a, int[] b) {
        return IntStream.range(0, Math.max(a.length, b.length))
                .map(i -> {
                    if(i < a.length && i < b.length)
                        return a[i] - b[i];
                    if(i < a.length)
                        return a[i];
                    return b[i];
                })
                .toArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is that if `number1 < number2`, calculate `number2 - number1`, and add a minus sign to the result. Of course, if there are equal, result is `0`.

You need to compare `number1` and `number2` as follows:

```
if (number1.length() == number2.length()) {
    if (number1 > number2) {
        // number1 is greater then number2.
    } else {
        // number2 is greater than number1.
    }
} else if (number1.length() > number2.length()) {
    // number1 is greater than number2.
} else
    // number2 is greater than number1.
}
```